# How to type a function in scala that may throw an exception?

Tags: scala, exception, throwable

I like to indicate that a function might throw an exception. Currently, I have a few validation functions in the form of:

```
val throwUnlessX: String => Unit = (foo: String) => {
  if (foo != "bar") {
    throw new Throwable("Poit!")
  }
}
```

It's typed with `Unit` as a return type, yet strictly speaking that's not entirely correct as the function may also never return as it may throw an exception instead.

Other languages have the concept of defining a `never` type, either for infinite loops or said exception throwing.

Is there something I can do to indicate to a developer that a function might throw or never returns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [@throws](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/throws.html) annotation to declare the exception that can be thrown by a method.

Showcased example:

> ```
> class Reader(fname: String) {
>   private val in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fname))
>   @throws[IOException]("if the file doesn't exist")
>   def read() = in.read()
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

There are types to represent these cases in Scala:

- a type can capture the notion of exception with `Try`; `Try[Unit]` in your case
- if you ascribe a type that has no instance as a return type, that will indicate that the function never returns, like `Nothing`

However, I strongly suggest the use of some validation library to your use case that does not throw exceptions; a good candidate would be [Scalaz](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Validation.html) for example.

Comment: Could you please expand the example for the `try` case? It seems that I then have to use Failure and Success, yet I don't know how to say: this is the success case, return with the success Unit.

Comment: Follow up to my comment: I was looking for `Success(())`.

Comment: In addition to `Try`, `Either` is a good option.  `Try` has the disadvantage of hiding the exception type, with either you can identify the specific exception that might be thrown, or even use a non-exception type as the error case.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply: I think you should use a validation framework. You can find [Try](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Try.html) and [Either](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Either.html) in the documentation.

Comment: The reply above is for the original question: how to represent exceptions and never returning functions with the type system of Scala. Was it not your intention to ask that?